# How to drag up UIContainer view in parent UIView within certain limits?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How would you go about dragging up a tab at the bottom of the screen like in apple maps and be able to drag it above the parent UIView, but keep it constrained within bounds of the screen.
i got this code which I'm trying to modify for my use case but I'm struggling to set the right bounds so it cant move up past a certain point and move down past a certain point.

```
var originalX: CGFloat = 0.0
var originalY: CGFloat = 0.0

@objc func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let panView = gesture.view else {
        return
    }
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(panView)
    var translatedPoint = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
    if gesture.state == .began {
        originalX = panView.center.x
        originalY = panView.center.y
    }
    
    translatedPoint = CGPoint(x: originalX, y: originalY + translatedPoint.y)
    print(originalY + translatedPoint.y)
    print(view.frame.height)
    if (originalY + translatedPoint.y) > view.frame.height {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        gesture.view?.center = translatedPoint
    } , completion: nil)
    }
}
```

new code with offset

```html
    var originalX: CGFloat = 0.0
    var originalY: CGFloat = 0.0
    var currentPoint: CGPoint?
    var position:CGPoint?
    

    @objc func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let panView = gesture.view else {
            return
        }
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(panView)
        var translatedPoint = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
        if gesture.state == .began {
            originalX = panView.center.x
            originalY = panView.center.y
        }
        
        
        
        translatedPoint = CGPoint(x: originalX, y: originalY + translatedPoint.y)
        //if offsetY >= 9 {
            
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            gesture.view?.center = translatedPoint
        } , completion: nil)
        //}
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            position = touch.location(in: view)
            //print("position\(position)")
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
            //print("currentPoint\(currentPoint)")
            let offsetY = currentPoint!.y - position!.y
            print(offsetY)
        }
    }
```

out put when dragging container view
2.0
0.5
9.0
1.0
8.0
0.5
4.0
7.5
-0.5
-6.5
-1.0
-8.0

output for dragging on uiview
-11.5
-21.5
-36.0
-52.0
-74.5
-86.5
-98.0
-102.0
-106.0
-112.0
-116.5
-120.0
-122.5
-124.0
-124.0
-124.0
-124.0
-124.0
-123.5
-120.5
-116.5
-114.0
-109.0
-104.5
-97.0
-89.0
-80.0
-74.0
-66.0
-58.5
-54.5
-49.5
-47.0
-42.5
-39.5
-35.5
-31.0
-28.5
-24.0
-21.5
-19.5
-18.0
-16.0
-15.5
-15.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that, and record the TouchPoint at TouchBegin（beginDrag） and get currentPoint at TouchMove（dragging）——I don't remember the specific agency method. By calculating offsetX = currentpoint.x - touchpoint.x. Using gestures to calculate is too complicated。

```
offsetX = currentpoint.x - touchpoint.x;
offsetY = currentpoint.y - touchpoint.y;
```

Comment: i can get the offset for the view but for the container view it isn't working, I get a constant stream for the view but the container view it changes from 9 to 4 to -4 and then 9 its not consistent

Comment: ill post the print and output

Comment: Did the coordinate conversion go wrong? You have to compute with the same view coordinates

Comment: and Don't use UIPanGestureRecognizer ，just use  touchesBegan、 touchesMoved